# Query grouped by month on multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

Ok, I'm grouping a query by month so I get a record for each month of the year, but I need to figure out how to do this: basically grouping by month on two different JOIN statements. I'm trying to get the count, or sum, of quantities in each child table if possible in one query. I could just loop through in php, but I'm trying to find a way to do in mysql.

Here's a sample

```
SELECT SUM(purchase_quantity),SUM(sales_quantity)
FROM products p
INNER JOIN purchase_order_lines sl ON pl.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN purchase_orders po ON pl.purchase_order_id = po.id
INNER JOIN sales_order_lines sl ON sl.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN sales_orders so ON sl.sales_order_id = so.id
GROUP BY YEAR(so.posted & po.posted), MONTH(so.posted & po.posted)
```

I know there's no way this would work, and the logic is ridiculous, and this isn't exactly the structure of my database, but just an idea of how things are linked and wwhat I'm trying to do. I'm thinking it would have to be done with subqueries in the SELECT statement, but I haven't come up with anything yet. I'll keep thinking about it, but if anyone has any ideas, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

because your grouping your result, you will get a count of one. why don't you try running a separate statement that will count the result and a separate statement to group it.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying exactly. I'm trying to find a way to do it in one select if possible. I've got a way that will work if I loop through the month ranges in my php code and just do the select for each month in the range, return the results and build an array from them. That's currently the only solution I've got, but hoping for a more efficient one that's not so heavy on queries if possible.